# Convert nvarchar to int in order to join SQL tables in a view

Tags: sql, int, inner-join, nvarchar, sql-view

I want to create a view which will display the info from two tables joined by different type fields. The one field is nvarchar and the other one is int. I know i need to convert one type in the other but don't know how to do it. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    SELECT dbo.co.co_num, dbo.pck_hdr.weight, dbo.STR_ShipTrack.TrackingNumber 
    FROM dbo.co 
INNER JOIN dbo.pck_hdr ON dbo.co.co_num = dbo.pck_hdr.co_num INNER JOIN dbo.STR_ShipTrack ON dbo.pck_hdr.pack_num = dbo.STR_ShipTrack.Reference1
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looking at your code, I can't tell either what you should do.

The SQL engine will do automatic conversions for the comparison.  However, if might decide to convert the character field to an integer -- and then get an error.

So, just cast your int field to nvarchar:

```
cast(IntField as nvarchar(255))
```

The length doesn't matter for an `nvarchar()` comparison.

In your query, you would replace:

```
ON dbo.pck_hdr.pack_num = dbo.STR_ShipTrack.Reference1
```

with:

```
ON cast(dbo.pck_hdr.pack_num as nvarchar(255)) = dbo.STR_ShipTrack.Reference1
```

Comment: I apologize for the incomplete description.  The dbo.pck_hdr.pack_num is the int and the dbo.STR_ShipTrack.Reference1 is the varchar(25) field. 
Can you please show me how I should put the code together?

Answer (score 1):

If you're casting from a string to an integer there's always a possibility you'll have a non-numeric content in the source column.

```
INNER JOIN Tab t on t.ColId = CONVERT(int, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(strCol) = 1 THEN strCol ELSE '-1' END)
```

Similar to @gordon-linhoff answer. But doing the comparison as int rather than string.